# How to initialize Paragraph Inlines

Tags: c#, wpf, flowdocument, paragraph

How can I initialize paragraph Inline with new InlineCollection? I defined InlineCollection and added Run elements with string to it. I tried to initialize this way

```
ParagraphComponent.Inlines = _inlineCollection;
```

However, I get error message that ParagraphComponent.Inline is readonly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Remarks section of the `Inlines` property page on MSDN:

> Use the InlineCollection returned by this property to enumerate or
>   manipulate the contents of a Paragraph element.

So you could do this:

```
ParagraphComponent.Inlines.Clear();
ParagraphComponent.Inlines.AddRange(_inlineCollection);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't Inlines is read only
You will need to add the Runs directly to the paragraph

In XAML you can define Inlines