# How to clear all properties from Paragraph.Inline

Tags: c#, wpf, flowdocument

Is it possible to clear all properties like (background color...) from Paragraph.Inline elements, just like you can do with class TextRange ?

---

Well, I wanted to clear background propery from previous Run element from Inline Collection. So I thought it would be easier to call a method which would clear all previous properties.
However, in my case, it seems the only way to do this is something like this:

```
int index = 0;
...
List<Inline> runList = ParagraphComponent.Inlines.ToList(); 
if (index < runList.Count) {
    if (index > 1) {
       int previousPartIndex = index - 2;
       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(runList[previousPartIndex].Text)) {
          runList[previousPartIndex].Background = null;
       }
    }
    runList[index].Background = BackgroundColor;
    index += 2;
}
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Hi Clemens! Please check edited post! p.s. Is it just me complicating things, or FlowDocument, Inlines components requries some practice time or it is really complicated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can't access the InlineCollection by index, I'd suggest to use the original `_inlineCollection` from which you initialize the Paragraph's Inlines (from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27888933/1136211)).

```
((Run)_inlineCollection[index]).Background = null;
index++;
while (index < inlineCollection.Count && !(_inlineCollection[index] is Run))
{
    index++;
}
if (index < _inlineCollection.Count)
{
    ((Run)_inlineCollection[index]).Background = BackgroundColor;
}
```

Comment: Thank you once more! `((Run)_inlineCollection[index]).BringIntoView();` This worked as well!